What do I need to know before starting Thrawn: Treason?
I've checked out the audiobook for Thrawn: Treason (2019) without reading/listening to the first two books (in my defense, my library only seems to have Treason – the third book – which I mistook for the first.)
I'm already almost halfway through and I'm a little lost between the Grisks and the Chiss.
Is there anything else I need to look into while I'm listening to this?

You'll need to know what treason is.  Apparently, "It" is treason. (then).
